# Select Content inside ImageView - Android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have an `Activity` containing an `ImageView` and I'd like to allow the User to select part of it's content with the touch (or mouse click) capabilities.

I'd like to write a procedure able to achieve two things:

1. Draw a highlighted window over the selected parts of the image
2. Return an object containing the coordinates of the selected (highlighted) pixels.

For better understanding you can check the little mock up I've created:

[image]

The User should touch the screen over some part of the image and it should get highlighted. When pressing the back button I'd like to obtain via Java the coordinates of the pixels that were highlighted.

Can you help me understand how to do?

In particular I'd like to find out the following:

1. should I access pixel level information of the image?
2. which classes are needed to implement this functionality?
3. some idea of pseudo code?

Thks for any kind of help!

Comment: -1
down vote
I know this is old but I need to do basically the same thing, I have ImageView with egg-like object and I want to call a method only when user clicks on the dimensions containing the object, not the whole ImageVIew. I see the answer here but still can't figure out how to distinguish if the user clicked on the object I would like inside the ImageView or on empty area in the ImageVIew as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would subclass `ImageView` then you can capture the touch events by overriding `onTouchEvent(...)`

When you get to the `onDraw(...)` method you can call super to draw the image as normal, then add your own code to draw a highlight over the top.

**EDIT**

Well instead of using `ImageView` you can extend it and write your own class, all this class has to do is override `onTouchEvent(...)` so you know when the view is being touched and can save the location on screen of the touch events. Next you edit the drawing methods:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas); // So the image you want is drawn as normal

    myMethodForDrawingAFancyHighlight(Canvas canvas); // add your special effects on top of the image
}
```

Comment: Thks for the prompt answer, but could you please help me understand better?I'm kind of a newbie...

Comment: I understand!just another technical question I have: the coordinates that are saved when a touch event is captured will be relative to the screen or to the pixels in the image?Because it is the latter ones that I want to memorise (the pixel ones)!If not, do you have any suggestions to work around the problem?

Comment: It will be the pixels relative to the view not the image. I would suggest trying to calculate the pixels in the image by looking at how much scrolling has been applied or what image offsets are used in the canvas etc. Good Luck